# Construction of an infinite set such that any two number from the set are relatively prime

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics

This question is taken from a contest in India.

- Prove that we can construct an infinite set of positive integers of the form $2^{n}-3$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that any two numbers from the set are relatively prime

I would like to have an answer for this question, and i would also like to know why $2^{n}-3$ has importance here. Can this question be generalized. That is:

- Can we construct an infinite set of positive integers of the form $k^{n} -(k+1)$ such that any two numbers from the set are relatively prime?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a set of odd primes $\displaystyle S = \{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_m \}$, we can find an $n$ such that $\displaystyle 2^n - 3 = 1 \mod p_i$, by choosing $n = 2 + \prod (p_i-1)$

Thus starting with

$\{2^2 -3,2^3 - 3\}$ we can add a new member which is relatively prime to all the previous members.

I believe a similar argument will hold for other $k$ (when considering $k^n -(k+1)$), since we will have $gcd(p_i,k) =1$.

Answer (score 4):

Further to Moron's answer, consider any sequence of the form x<sub>n</sub> = a<sup>n</sup> + b for fixed integers a,b. Is there an infinite set of the x<sub>n</sub> for which any two are coprime?

First, any common factor of a and b will divide every x<sub>n</sub>. Furthermore, for any n,
$$
x_n=(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a+1)(a-1)+(b+1).
$$
so any common factor of a − 1 and b + 1 will divide every x<sub>n</sub>. The answer to the question is no if either a, b or a − 1, b + 1 have a common prime factor.

If a, b are coprime and every factor of b + 1 divides a then the answer is yes.
Let S = {p<sub>1</sub>,...,p<sub>m</sub>} be a finite set of primes not dividing a. Taking n to be a multiple of ∏<sub>k</sub>(p<sub>k</sub> − 1) gives x<sub>n</sub> = 1 + b ≠ 0 (mod p<sub>k</sub>), so is not a multiple of p<sub>k</sub>. If S is the set of prime factors of any finite collection of the x<sub>n</sub>, this shows that we can find a new x<sub>n</sub> coprime to each of the ones so far and, by induction, we can find an infinite set.

This shows that the answer is yes in the cases you mention a = 2, b = -3 and a = k, b = -(k + 1). It does, however, leave open the cases where a,b are coprime and b + 1 has prime factors not dividing a or a − 1.