# Why is the recurrent sequence $\bmod p$ reversible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

A [constant-recursive sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence) is $$x_{i+m} = a_{m-1}x_{i+m-1} + a_{m-2}x_{i+m-2} + \cdots + a_0x_i,\tag{*} $$ where $m$ is the order of sequence and $a_i$ is integer.

If we take it by $\bmod p$, we get:

$${x_{i + m}} = {a_{m - 1}}{x_{i + m - 1}} + {a_{m - 2}}{x_{i + m - 2}} +  \cdots  + {a_0}{x_i}\pmod{p}$$

How can we prove that if not $p{|}{a_j}$ for all $j \in 0,...,m - 1$, then we get a reversible periodic sequence $\bmod p$?

This fact is used, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/719815/560521).

Comment: There are only finitely many $m$-tuples of remainders modulo $p$. As soon as the $m$-tuple formed by $m$ consecutive terms of the sequence re-appears, the next term would be the same as the first time the $m$-tuple occurred. It $a_k$ is the coefficient with smallest $k$ that is not divisible by $p$, then you can solve for $x_{i+k}$ in terms of $x_{i+k+1},...,x_{i+m}$, since $a_k$ has an inverse modulo $p$.

Comment: @plop Thanks for the answer! But this does not give the periodicity from the beginning of the sequence. For example, the sequence $$\{1, 2, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4,...\}$$ and $p=4$ give $$\{1, 2, 0, 0, 0, ...\}$$ It will not be reversible, since there is $\{1, 2\}$ at the beginning

Comment: `\pmod{p}` automatically gives the spacing and the parentheses for the expression.

Comment: I see, you don't want $p$ prime. Note that $2$ doesn't have an inverse modulo $4$. Then. as you have shown the statement is not true in that case. In the linked question they are talking about $p$ being a prime.

Comment: I call this [**reinventing the wheel (cycle)**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/34795/242). Alas, such reinventions happen [far too frequently.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20reinventing%20the%20wheel).